# Casting to parent class with losing information - store parts of an object

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

I have a class `Bucket` with lots of informations, of which I only want to store (serializable) two fields into a file. Because of that, I made `Bucket` extend `ChatData` which only holds those two fields, because I thought that when upcasting, I could lose the useless information and store the `bucket` object as a `chatdata` object then.

But instead, upcasting to a super class does not make the object lose its subclass information. How can I achieve this?

```
public class ChatData implements Serializable {
    private int f1 = 1;
    private int f2 = 2;
}

public class Bucket extends ChatData implements Serializable {
    private int f3 = 3;
    private int f4 = 4;    // useless data when it comes to storing
    private int f5 = 5;
    public void store(ObjectOutputStream oos) {
        oos.writeObject( (ChatData) this );    // does also store f3, f4, f5,
        // ... but I don't whant these!
        // also, unnecessary cast, does not do anything
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bucket b = new Bucket();
        b.store(new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/output.dat"));
    }
}
```

(untested code, only for visualization)

How can I write my `Bucket` object as a `ChatData` object to my hard drive? If not, what would be the preferred way to store an object only partially?

I could think of an easy solution like creating a completely new `ChatData` object, but I would rather understand what's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to serialize a member of a class. Just mark it as `transient`.

In your particular case, you don't need to go through the trouble of creating a super class. Do this instead :

```
public class Bucket implements Serializable {
    transient private int f3 = 3;
    transient private int f4 = 4;    // useless data when it comes to storing
    transient private int f5 = 5;
    private int f1 = 1;
    private int f2 = 2;

   //leave the remaining code in this class as it is
}
```

Comment: this somehow does barely save any hard drive space at all, although half of the data should be missing... no idea why.. but it works anyway, thanks